# cant handle response because its having Backslash in it

Tags: javascript, json, response, backslash

```json
"{\"MarketModelDomains\": [{\"MarketModelDomainID\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Analytic Applications\",\"Description\":\"Analytic applications are packaged BI capabilities that address a particular domain or industry vertical business problem. Their advantage is that, as packaged solutions, they provide faster deployments and easier maintenance, and they incorporate domain expertise and best practices.\"}]}"
```

Comment: what makes you think that? - the console can be deceiving if you don't know what you're looking at - looks like a string ... in JSON format

Comment: Did you try to parse the String? JSON.parse("...")

Comment: Can you please show us how do you get this response with an example?

Comment: What do you mean with can't handle response? Could you show us *how* you are trying to handle the response? This string seems perfectly valid to pass to `JSON.parse()`, or if you are using `fetch()` you can call `response.json()` instead.

Comment: I used JSON.parse in all the possible ways. But unable to use this resonse in Front End.
I suppose to use Names in this list as a list in Datalist.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a matter of parsing the string into an object. Something like this:

```js
var str = "{\"MarketModelDomains\": [{\"MarketModelDomainID\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Analytic Applications\",\"Description\":\"Analytic applications are packaged BI capabilities that address a particular domain or industry vertical business problem. Their advantage is that, as packaged solutions, they provide faster deployments and easier maintenance, and they incorporate domain expertise and best practices.\"}]}";

var object = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(object.MarketModelDomains[0].Name);
```